# How Can I Get Packages From Other Repositories?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, repository

I am trying to setup a cluster with 2 computers for the first time. I have searched for tutorials for how to do it on linux mint, but the only tutorials I can find are for redhat instead of mint. I meet my first road block when trying to follow this tutorial when using 'yum'. I don't believe you can, or should use yum on linux. The packages I am trying to install is "ricci","luci","ccs", and "cman", all of which are not in the linux mint 20.1 repository. I am wondering if and how you can access other linux repositories. I am aware that you can download things from gitgub using the command "git clone". Any knowledge will be helpful!

Comment: You were probably looking at *very* outdated tutorials. Redhat switched to pacemaker/corosync and you appear to find only *old* documentation for RHEL6 about luci&co. So search again for tutorials about pacemaker/corosync for Debian based systems (try to find modern documentation)

Comment: Yeah, that's really ancient.  you probably want to use SLURM  (Simple Linux Utility For Resource Management) instead.  On Debian (and on Mint), there are several slurm-related packages, but the main one is `slurm-wlm`.    I've built a few linux clusters over the years, and IMO it's the best no-compromises open source clustering system. There's a very brief overview of SLURM at [SLURM-A workload manager designed for Linux clusters of any size](https://www.fossmint.com/slurm-a-workload-manager-designed-for-linux-clusters/)

Comment: BTW, what kind of jobs do you want to run on your cluster?   If it's just compiling software, you may be better off with `distcc`.   Also note, for computational stuff, you'll probably want to install Open MPI too, and your software should be written to use it.